# Send an ajax request every time that a form input field change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm need to create a form that sends an ajax request everytime a form element is changed using the jQuery change event. I was able to get the form input values to show up in spans by doing this:

```
<form id="TestForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="namefirst" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your first name" /><span id="spanfirstname"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="namelast" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your last name" /><span id="spanlastname"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="left-inner-addon"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
                <input id="email" type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email" /><span id="spanemail"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="left-inner-addon"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt"></i>
                <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your phone number" /><span id="spanphone"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a password" /><span id="spanphone"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <button class="button green major beeboop" name="button" type="submit">This is a test</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
<div class="row spacer"></div>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#firstname').change(function() {
            $('#output_firstname').val($(this).val());
            $('#spanfirstname').html('<b> TestForm: firstname:' + $(this).val() + '</b>');
        });
        $('#lastname').change(function() {
            $('#output_lastname').val($(this).val());
            $('#spanlastname').html('<b>' + $(this).val() + '</b>');
        });
        $('#email').change(function() {
            $('#output_email').val($(this).val());
            $('#spanemail').html('<b>' + $(this).val() + '</b>');
        });
        $('#phone').change(function() {
            $('#output_phone').val($(this).val());
            $('#spanphone').html('<b>' + $(this).val() + '</b>');
        });
        $('#password').change(function() {
            $('#output_password').val($(this).val());
            $('#spanpassword').html('<b>' + $(this).val() + '</b>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I tried the wrap the ajax request in the change event function with no success:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#firstname').change(function() {
            jQuery.post("ajax-process.cfm", {
                firstname: jQuery('#firstname').val()
            }, function(data) {

            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

@omar-ali @Anil Namde Updated the code. But now I'm only getting the first value in the console:

```
$("input[type='text']").change(function() {
var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
$.ajax({
url : "ajax-process.cfm",
type: "POST",
data: {
    firstname: firstname,
    lastname: lastname,
    email: email
},
success: function(data) {
$("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code>' + data +  '</code></pre>');
}
});
});
```

Comment: you should describe your issue (error, result you get, etc...), 'no success' means nothing

Comment: why you return false in change?

Comment: Have you checked for the logs in browser dev CONSOLE ? are there any messages ? More & precise information would help you get correct answers.

Comment: Check this.. http://www.pontikis.net/blog/jquery-ui-autocomplete-step-by-step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code, but instead of calling any ajax request, I just put a `console.log('testing');`

It works.

I guess what you don't realize (my feeling) is that.. the change is called not as you type..but once you lose focus from the text-box.

Also, it's better to use

```js
var getallyourvalshere = $('#firstname').val();

$.post('linktoyourscript.php',{ firstname: getallyourvalshere }, function(data) {
    //do stuff, console.log(data); 
});
```

Why are you using return false;

Comment: It's working! Thank you and everyone that helped. I needed to add the form values to the struct was my other issue.